# Search special characters using to_tsquery

Tags: full-text-search, postgresql-9.1

How to construct to_tsquery to search for special characters like , "_", etc... ?

I have entry in my tsvector column like "v_130" and I would like to search for "v_130" but when I construct to_tsquery such as to_tsquery('v_130:*') it doesn't return any records.

Comment: I tried it searching as 'v\_130' and it work, but now I have another issue I have another entry as 'v-1-3-0' and when I search for 'v\_' it also shows both records

Comment: ahh the comment ignored special character 'back slash'

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is happening because Special Characters are counted as Blanks/Spaces in POstgres FTS.